# Missing ABI error for web3.eth.Contract() method

Tags: web3js, abi

I have the following js code

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

const nodeUrl = "my node url";

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(nodeUrl));

const contractAbi = '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_WETH","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"WETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountADesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveB","type":"uint256"}],"name":"quote","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapETHForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]';

const contractId = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D";

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractId);

contract.getPastEvents('Transfer', {
    fromBlock: 6718108,
    toBlock: 'latest'
}, function(error, events) {
    if(!error) {
        console.log(events);
    }
});
```

When I run the code it returns the following error:

```
/home/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:61
        throw errors.ContractMissingABIError();
        ^

Error: You must provide the json interface of the contract when instantiating a contract object.
    at Object.ContractMissingABIError (/home/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:107:16)
    at Contract (/home/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:61:22)
    at new Contract (/home/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/index.js:258:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/getUniswapTxs.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

I got the ABI for the contract from Etherscan, but it does not seem to work here. What is the problem with the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have your ABI in JSON format (list or dictionary), not as string